# How to split dataset into (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

The training and validations datasets I am using are [shared here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-_dvey1kwLJoqfIdf4nxfkvWAqE1gL81?usp=sharing) for the sake of reproducibility.

The `validation_dataset.csv` is the ground truth of `training_dataset.csv`.

What I am doing below is feeding the datasets into a simple CNN layer that extracts the useful features of the images and feed that as 1D into the LSTM network for classification.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt

df_train = genfromtxt('data/train/training_dataset.csv', delimiter=',') 
df_validation = genfromtxt('data/validation/validation_dataset.csv', delimiter=',') 

#train,test = train_test_split(df_train, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)


df_train = df_train[..., None] 
df_validation = df_validation[..., None]


batch_size=8
epochs=5
    
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
#model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
callbacks = [EarlyStopping('val_loss', patience=3)]


model.fit(df_train, df_validation, batch_size=batch_size)

print(model.summary())

   
scores = model.evaluate(df_train, df_validation, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

I want to split the training and validation dataset into `(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)` so that I can use both datasets for training and testing. I tried the split function of the Scikit-learn library -`train,test = train_test_split(df_train, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)` but it is giving me the following error after we invoke the `model.fit()` function.

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 14384
  y sizes: 3596
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

How can we split the dataset into `(X_train, y_train)`, `(X_test, y_test)` sharing the same dimension?

Comment: `train_test_split` returns `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test` in that order you've assigned `y_train` to what should be `x_test`

Comment: @Marcus you miss to specify a target

Comment: you are defining `train,test = train_test_split(df_train, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)`but when training you are still calling your original `df_train` instead of `train` and `test`

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel, I just did that to avoid the error.

Comment: @Andrew, it says `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to have X and Y sets. Here, I assume the column name for Y is 'target'.

```
target = df_train['target']
df_train = df_train.drop(columns=['target'])
```

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_train, target, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)

--

It seems that I had initially misunderstood your problem, and "validation_dataset.csv" is your label data. I apologize for not reading correctly.

In this case, you do not need a "target" variable, as that is what df_validation would be. Therefore, I think the following may work:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_train, df_validation, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
```

Comment: Thank you, Adam. But when I do that I am getting this error `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: is the error from the train_test_split line or another line?

Comment: No, it is on `target = df_train['target']`. We don't have column names by the way. It is a pixel data

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I am a little confused on your dataset though. df_train is images? so does that mean df_validation are the labels or are they images aswell? or are you doing something else?

Comment: I just read from another comment where you stated that "validation_dataset.csv" are labels. I will edit the answer.

Comment: As you can see it here (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ByiWaufttLRYeUP_NgQfUgjdA2rpCNli?usp=sharing), there are two folders - images and labels (both image files). So the labels folder contains the ground-truth (labels) for the images files inside the images folder. Since Keras was having a problem identifying the satellite images with .TIF extension, I decided to convert them to Numpy array and that's what the `training_dataset.csv` and `validation_dataset.csv` represent in the code I shared.

Comment: Okay, I am still not getting it. What are you trying to predict, as in, what are you Y values? If df_train is your X.

Comment: Finally, I am trying to classify the images as per the labels given inside the labels folder here (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ByiWaufttLRYeUP_NgQfUgjdA2rpCNli?usp=sharing)